# Задача. Массивы

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу:

> Дана целочисленная прямоугольная
> матрица А размером nxm. Найти в
> матрице первую строку, все элементы
> которой равны нулю. Умножить все
> элементы столбца с таким же номером на
> 2.

Подскажите метод решения этой задачи.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 0, 4, 6, 2 },   // Создаем
                                      { 3, 4, 1, 7, 4 },   // Массив
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },   // размером
                                      { 7, 8, 2, 4, 1 } }; // nxm
        Console.WriteLine("Исходный массив:");
        for (int i = 0; i < array2D.GetLength(0); i++ )
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2D.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (array2D[i, j] == 0)
                Console.Write(" " + array2D[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("  ");
        }
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

В данной матрице в строке №3 все элементы равны 0 ее надо найти, и столбец 3 умножить на 2. Как это осуществить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 0, 4, 6, 2 },   // Создаем
                              { 3, 4, 1, 7, 4 },   // Массив
                              { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },   // размером
                              { 7, 8, 2, 4, 1 } }; // nxm

int result=-1;;
List<int> tmp = new List<int>();

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{   
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        tmp.Add(array2D[i,j]);
    if(tmp.All(num=>num==0))// альтернатива: !tmp.Any(num=>num!=0)
    {
        result = i;
        break;
    }
    tmp.Clear();
}

if(result!=-1)// проверка на случай, если необходимой строки нету
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        array2D[i,result]*=2;
```

Comment: Спасибо! А можно еще каким нибудь методом решить эту задачу?

Comment: Можно не создавать вспомогательный список tmp, а просто использовать логическую (bool) переменную для выяснения, является ли строка нулевой.

Comment: А можно пример?
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Ну например:

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            bool allZeroes = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                allZeroes &= array2D[i, j] == 0;
            // Поскольку на нули умножение не влияет, то...
            if(allZeroes && i < m)  // все нули и столбец существует
                for(int i1=0; i1<array2D.GetLength(0); i1++) array2D[i1, i] *= 2;
        }

Comment: а мне нравится, особенно с оператором ``&=``